# Is `terraform init` compulsory before every `terraform plan`?

Tags: terraform

Just wondering if `terraform init` is compulsory before every `terraform plan`?

i.e. if I've already done a `terraform init` but are about to do a second `terraform plan` based on some changed Terraform code would you need to do a second `terraform init`?

Answer (score 7):

It depends.

Depending on exactly what the Terraform code is you've changed, you *may* need to re-run init.  For instance, if you've made changes to a configured backend, you'll need to rerun `terraform init` to re-initialise with those changes.  If the changes are to non-terraform configuration parts of your script, `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` should be fine to use by themselves.

One further note is that if you're using modules, and you make a change in a module, you will need to re-run `terraform get -update` to get those changes before running `plan` or `apply`.

Comment: In the forthcoming 0.10 release, the `init` command has the additional responsibility of installing provider plugins, so adding the first resources for a new provider will be a further reason to re-run it.

Comment: As stated in their [blog post](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/upcoming-provider-changes-in-terraform-0-10/).

Comment: @James Thorpe Can you please elabrate more on term you used " configured backend " and "  non-terraform configuration parts "

Answer (score 3):

Agree with all the above answers, but something to add here is that it is safe to run terraform init many times even if nothing changed, its not going to affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

`terraform init` running state depends on what has been changes, in case there are changes in plugins or your backend configs.
This command is always safe to run multiple times, to bring the working directory up to date with changes in the configuration. Though subsequent runs may give errors, this command will never delete your existing configuration or state.

So, you can run init every time you run `terraform plan` to keep things up to date.
In case there are no change then you skip it.
However, if multiple people are working on the project & you are storing state somewhere then always run `terraform init` before running `terraform plan`.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the situation.`terraform init` command is used to initialize a working directory containing Terraform configuration files. If you weren't changed the terraform configurations(key words you can say) you don't need to issue a  `terraform init`. Instead you can `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`. Usually terraform tell, if terraform need be initialize by a messege